# Do not prefix routes with Rails Engine name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I am converting an app to use Rails engines. I have an engine located in `engines/web` folder. In `config/routes.rb` I mount it like this:

`mount Web::Engine => '/', as: 'web_engine'`

The folder structure is like this:

```
config
  routes.rb
engines
  web
    config
      routes.rb
    app
      controllers
        web 
          application_controller.rb
          ...
    lib
      ...
```

Engine is defined like this:

```
module Web
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Web
  end
end
```

My application controller inside of Web engine is defined like this:

```
module Web
  class ApplicationController < ::ActionController::Base
    layout 'web/layouts/application'

    # other code
  end
end
```

The problem is that inside of `Web::ApplicationController` I have to refer to routes as `web_engine.my_route_path` and not as `my_route_path`. Is there a way to access routes without `web_engine` prefix from inside of Web engine?

Comment: Hi Andrew. Could you please update your question with the code on your engines/web/config/routes.rb, config/routes files and the output of rake/routes?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
module Web
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Web
  end
end
```

See [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes) for details about routes. Also check out `Engine.isolate_namespace` description.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I cannot tell if this will force the engine files to be restructured.

Comment: @NewAlexandria routes section is written on the assumption that you use isolated namespace. It containts these words: `For instance, the following example would go to the application's posts_path if that template was rendered from the application, or the engine's posts_path if it was rendered from the engine: link_to "Blog posts", posts_path`.

Comment: This is what I have. Still inside of controllers in Web engine I have to prefix all routes with "web": `web.my_route_path`

Comment: @AndrewBezzub it's definitely should work. Here is some very nice description: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html . I did a test and everything worked well. Also I had to change railsties' loading order (see docs for my link for details for option called railties_order) via `config.railties_order = [TestEngine::Engine, :main_app, :all]` to make it work with mounting to '/'. Try it.

Comment: @FlashGordon looking at your link, [it says that the engine's paths are called exactly the way](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#class-Rails::Engine-label-Using+Engine%27s+routes+outside+Engine) that Andrew *does not* want to call them; as `my_engine.root_url`

Comment: @NewAlexandria it's about using route helpers _outside_ an engine. And Andrew wants to use them _inside_ one without prefixing.

Answer (score 0):

Include your url helpers inside your engine's controller:

```
module Web
  class ApplicationController < ::ActionController::Base
    helper Web::Enginer.routes.url_helpers

  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You must

1- remove the line `isolated_namespace` from you _engine_path_/lib/web/engine.rb file (I assume you know the consequences in terms of risks of object naming colliding)

2- remove the line `mount Web::Engine ...` from your _app_path_/config/route.rb file

3- define your routes in your engine in a `Rails.application.routes.draw` block. So your _engine_path_/config/routes.rb look like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :things
  get 'my_path', to: 'my_controller#my_action'
end
```

Then your routes defined in your engine won't be prefixed by the engine name

And you will have access to your route helpers from your engine in your app and vice-versa, without prefix and without scoping to your engine name

Comment: is there a way to not prefix routes with mountable engine?

Comment: I am OK with prefixing routes in the app, I don't want them to be prefixed in code that is part of the engine

Comment: `is there a way to not prefix routes with mountable engine? ` Well yes that's what my answer is about. Just follow the 3 steps in my answer and your routes won't be prefixed anymore

Comment: it is not a "mountable" engine

Comment: Look, I have on project with 5 engine, and my routes are not prefixed. Follow my steps and it will work. Guaranteed

Comment: No. I as I said earlier I need a mountable engine that uses "isolated_namespace"

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need mountable engine? Are you going to distribute your gem? As per your description it seems not but I can be wrong on that. If not you don't need it to be mountable